Connection between definition of topological continuity and the quotient topology
Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. A map $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for every open subset $U\subseteq Y$.
If we now require $Y$ to be merely a set and $f$ to be surjective, the quotient topology on $Y$ determined by $f$ is defined by declaring $U$ open iff $f^{-1}(U)$ open.
Topology is new to me, but I feel like there should be some intuitive connection between the two concepts. At the moment, nothing comes to mind. Any explanation would be appreciated! Thank you.

The quotient topology is the roughest topology making the projection continuous

Err, actually it’s the finest topology with a continuous projection (if you give Y the trivial topology, $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is still continuous.)

Note that this still works when $f$ is not surjective, but the points not in the image of $f$ are discrete: if $y \notin f(X)$, then $f^{-1}(y) = \emptyset$, which is open. so ${y}$ is an open set. The reason for the restriction to surjective sets is so we can consider $Y$ to be the space of equivalence classes of $X$ under the relation $x \sim u \iff f(x) = f(u)$. And it works in the other direction as well: If $Y$ is a topological space and $f : X \to Y$. then the set ${f^{-1}(U) \mid U\text{ open in }X}$ is the coarsest topology on $X$ making $f$ continuous.

Let $(X,\mathcal{T}_X)$ be a topological space. If we denote $\sim$ an equivalence relation on $X$, then the quotient topology, as its name suggests, is the "proper" topology which can be defined in the set of equivalence classes $X/\sim$. Notice that this induces the canonical map $\pi:X\to X/\sim$, which is surjective, and obeys that $x_1\sim x_2$ if and only if $\pi(x_1)=\pi(x_2)$. This can be also done for any surjective map $f:X\to Y$. That is, we can define on $X$ the following equivalence relation: $x_1\sim_f x_2\Leftrightarrow f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.  Hence, the quotient topology is usually introduced in its general setting: is the "proper" topology $\mathcal{T}_Y$ defined in $Y$ given by the surjective map $f:X\to Y$.
Now, what do we mean by "proper"? Well, first of all, since $f:X\to Y$ relates the new set $Y$ with the prior topological space $X$ (as well as $\pi:X\to X/\sim$), it is natural to require to that topology to make $f$ continuous. So the next question to ask ourselves is: which $\mathcal{T}_Y$ makes $f$ continuous? And the answer is: many of them (depending on the set $Y$). Not only that, but we can always choose $\mathcal{T}_Y$ to be the trivial topology: if $A=\varnothing$ or $A=Y$, then $f^{-1}(A)=\varnothing\in\mathcal{T}_X$ or $X\in\mathcal{T}_X$ respectively, satisfying the conditions of continuity. This fact implies the following (albeit vaguely explained) idea: the fewer open sets $\mathcal{T}_Y$ contains, the closer will be $f$ to be continuous.
Hence, the following question can be asked: from all $\mathcal{T}_Y$ that makes $f$ continuous, which is the one with the most open sets (i.e., the finest topology)? This is the definition of the quotient topology on $Y$. With this definition let us see that, indeed, $U\in\mathcal{T}_Y\Leftrightarrow f^{-1}(U)\in\mathcal{T}_X$. First of all, by the definition of the quotient topology, $f$ is continuous, so $U\in\mathcal{T}_Y\Rightarrow f^{-1}(U)\in\mathcal{T}_X$. On the other hand, by contradiction, suppose that $f^{-1}(U)\in\mathcal{T}_X$ and $U\notin\mathcal{T}_Y$. Then the topology genererated by $\mathcal{T}_Y$ and $U$ is a strictly finer topology than $\mathcal{T}_Y$ that makes $f$ continuous, contradicting the hypothesis that $\mathcal{T}_Y$ is the finest. Hence, $f^{-1}(U)\in\mathcal{T}_Y\Rightarrow U\in\mathcal{T}_Y$.
From this we can conclude that: given $(X,\mathcal{T})$ a topological space and $f:X\to Y$ a surjective map: if $Y$ has the quotient topology, $f$ is continuous. However, the other implication does not hold: it is easy to find some example of $f:X\to Y$, where $Y$ has the trivial topology (so $f$ is continuous) which is not the quotient topology.
Remark: The quotient topology and the equivalence relation
From the first paragraph, surjective maps and equivalence relations are equivalent definitions: any equivalence relation $\sim$ define a surjective map $\pi$ and any surjective map $f$ define an equivalence relation $\sim_f$ whose canonical map $\pi_{\sim_f}=f$. Nevertheless, from the topological point of view, these two perspective do not coincide. In particular, we need to impose a new condition: $f$ must be an open map (i.e., $f(U)\in\mathcal{T}_Y$ for all $U\in\mathcal{T}_X$). With this, we get the following result:

Let $(X,\mathcal{T}_X)$ a topological space and $f:X\to Y$. Suppose that $f$ is surjective and open, and $Y$ has the quotient topology. If we define the equivalence relation $x_1\sim_f x_2\Leftrightarrow f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, then $$ X/\sim_f\cong Y.$$

